# SUM values in a loop while

Tags: php, while-loop

I'am looking for a way to count in a table the number of people who belong to a group ( groupe1 in the example) and to a specific hour ( 09:00 )
Actually my echo result is : 2000000000. (Indeed i have 2 people in my table who match to the 2 conditions). How can I display only the result  "2" ( that is to say addition the values 2+0+0+0+0+0+0+0 .. )

Thank you

This is my actual code:

```
$r2=$my->query_array($sql2);

$counter=0;

$today=date('H:i',strtotime($row['heure']));


  while ($row2=$r2->fetch_array()) {

       if ($row2['groupe'] == 'groupe1' && $today == '09:00')
       $counter++ ;

      }

 echo $counter;
```

Update :

```
   while ($row=$r->fetch_array()) {

       if ($row['type']=='test1') {
          $sql2 = 'SELECT  ... ';  //( my request)

          $r2=$my->query_array($sql2);

          $counter=0;
          $today=date('H:i',strtotime($row['heure']));

                while ($row2=$r2->fetch_array()) {

                if ($row2['libellee'] == 'groupe1' && $today == '09:00')
                $counter++ ;

     $t.= '<tr><td class="text">'.$txt_annule.'&nbsp;       '.$row2['nom'].' '.$row2['prenom'].'</td>'.PHP_EOL;
     $t.= '<td  class="text">'.date('H:i',strtotime($row2['heure'])).'</td>'.PHP_EOL;
     $t.= '<td class="text">'.$row2['libellee'].' </td>'.PHP_EOL;
     $t.= '</tr>'.PHP_EOL;
        }

        echo $counter;      
        }

          else if ($row['type']=='test2') {

      $t.= '<tr><td class="text">'.$txt_annule.'&nbsp;&nbsp '.$row2['nom'].' '.$row2['prenom'].'</td>'.PHP_EOL;
      $t.= '<td class="text">'.date('H:i',strtotime($row2['heure'])).'</td>'.PHP_EOL;
      $t.= '<td class="text">'.$row2['libellee'].' </td>'.PHP_EOL;
      $t.= '</tr>'.PHP_EOL;     
            }       
    }
```

Comment: That code as shown should not output `2000000000`. Show us the actual code.

Comment: There's no way this code could produce the output you've said it does.

Comment: set `$counter=0;` before the `while` loop

Comment: this is the same result

Answer (score 0):

hey can not you just try like this, not sure if the most elegant solution but I guess will work

```
$counter = 0;    
while ($row2=$r2->fetch_array()) {
     if ($row2['groupe'] == 'groupe1' && $today == '09:00') {
      $newCount = $counter+1;
      $counter = $newCount;
     }
    }

    echo $newCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using pure SQL solution instead of fetching all records and counting. It may cause performance problems as database table grows.
For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people WHERE groupe = 5 and TIME(heure) = '09:00'
```

This query will return exact number of people.